# Install Orfeo Plugin in QGIS - Plugin is not already in QGIS core

Tags: qgis, installation, classification, orfeo-toolbox, image-classification

I am brand new to QGIS (coming from ArcGIS), and am needing to install the Orfeo toolbox to do some image classification. I found a nice tutorial here with an overview on how to install it: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/QGISInterface.html#open-processing-settings . However, I'm still having trouble with it.

The tutorial specifically states that if you are running a version of QGIS greater than 3.8 (I am running 3.14), the Orfeo Toolbox (OTB) core should already be under the "installed" tab on the plugins manager. However, it is not, and I do not know where to go from here!

I downloaded the OTB from https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/download/ , but cannot seem to find the OTB core. What can I do to install this toolbox? Like I said, I'm brand new to this program, so I'm having some trouble accomplishing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the Plugins Manager, you will need to work on `Options` (from the menu `Settings > Options`).

[image]

1. In the `Options` window, select `Processing` section (lowermost tab). You will find the **OTB**. Expand the **OTB** tree.
2. Double-click on an empty area next to `OTB application folder`. There an ellipsis button ([...]) will appear.
3. Click on the [...] button and open `Multiple selection` window.
4. Click on [Add] button and go to where you have downloaded the OTB tool. Drill down to `OTB-7.1.0-Win64/lib/otb/application`.
5. Then click on [OK] to close the window.
6. Double-click another empty area next to `OTB folder`. Select `OTB-7.1.0-Win64` by doing the same as the above.
7. Activate it.

[image]

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!